# How can I extract docs data from a WRI Workbench template?

Tags: documentation

I would like to move my docs out of Workbench in [something simpler](https://github.com/b3m2a1/SimpleDocs), but it's painful to imagine moving over all of the pages that I already have. DocuTools has lots of custom style names and has become complicated and bloated over time, so I can't just copy paste into something new.

Is there a way I can get all the data from my Workbench docs templates programmatically and move it to something else?

Answer (score 7):

This effort was born of trying to make [Chris K's life easier](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49808739#49808739). To move his stuff from Workbench, which is out-of-date, complicated, and clunky to my bare bones but cross-version, simple to use system we it had to be easy to move his docs.

To that end we'll basically do two things: 1) segment the notebook 2) transform the chunks

### Notebook Segmentation

These templates look like this:

[image]

Obviously they look a little nicer with the actual stylesheet they're supposed to have, but in general they're basically just a bunch of cells indicating either metadata or sections. We want to split this so every section becomes a key in an `Association` and so that we have all the metadata.

I did this by defining some cell styles that would define where a new section starts and mapping them to tags. This is what that function looks like:

```
getStyleType[sname_] :=
 Catch[
  If[StringStartsQ[sname, "Related"],
   Throw[StringTrim[sname, "Section"]]
   ];
  KeyValueMap[
   If[StringEndsQ[sname, #], Throw[#2]] &,
   <|
    "Title" | "ObjectName" -> "Body",
    "FunctionsSection" -> "Body",
    "ExampleSection" -> "Examples",
    "ExamplesSection" -> "Examples",
    "MoreAboutSection" -> "RelatedGuides",
    "TutorialsSection" -> "RelatedTutorials",
    "SeeAlsoSection" -> "RelatedFunctions"
    |>
   ];
  None
  ]
```

Then I `Sow` every `cell` with the current tag, updating it if the style is right:

```
nbData =
 GroupBy[
  Reap[
    Do[
     Replace[
      getStyleType@cell[[2]], 
      s_String :> Set[ctag, s]
      ];
     Sow[cell, ctag],
     {cell, cellData}
     ],
    _,
    Rule
    ][[2]],
  First -> Last,
  processCellSections
  ]
```

And with that I have an `Association` telling me what all my sections are.

I also want to pull all my metadata. To do that I leverage the fact that each metadata entry has a `CellLabel` and its content is a `String`. Here's how I do that segmentation:

```
{Pick[cellData, #], Pick[cellLabels, #]}&@Map[StringQ, cellLabels]
```

where `cellData` is basically just `NotebookRead@Cells[]` and `cellLabels` is `CurrentValues[Cells[], CellLabel]`

### Chunk Transformation

#### Metadata

This is a rather more involved process. To start off with, we need to transform the metadata we just pulled. I do that like so:

```
extractMetadata[cellData_, cellLabels_] :=
 With[
  {
   basics =
    AssociationThread[
     cellLabels /. {
       "Entity Type" -> "Type",
       "Paclet Name" -> "Paclet"
       },
     cellData[[All, 1]]
     ]
   },
  Normal@
    Merge[
     {
      DeleteCases[
       basics,
       "XXXX" | Except[_String]
       ],
      "Label" -> URLParse[basics["URI"], "Path"][[-1]]
      },
     First
     ] // BTools`Paclets`DocGen`DocMetadata
  ]
```

That `` BTools`Paclets`DocGen`DocMetadata `` is a function I wrote for a documentation system a long time ago to fill out all the necessary metadata for a documentation notebook. You can see how it's defined [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/a24e94f43fe7f158bc56bcb92cd83e44d2e1862f/Packages/Paclets/DocGen/DocGenCore.m#L1073).

#### Style Conversions

Next we have to convert over the content itself. For the most part this can just be achieved through some style conversions. That could look like:

```
styleConvert // Clear;
fallbackStyleConversions =
  Dispatch@{
    "TI" :> Sequence @@ {"InlineFormula", FontSlant -> Italic},
    "ModInfo" -> "Text",
    "Notes" -> "Item",
    "SeeAlso" -> "Text",
    "ObjectName" -> "Section",
    "GuideTitle" -> "Section",
    "MoreAbout" -> "Text",
    "Tutorials" -> "Text",
    "GuideAbstract" -> "Text",
    "InlineGuideFunction" :> Sequence @@ {"InlineFormula", "Input"},
    "InlineFormula" :> Sequence @@ {"InlineFormula", "Input"},
    "DisplayMath" :> 
     Sequence @@ {"DisplayFormulaNumbered", TextAlignment -> Center},
    _String?(StringStartsQ["Related"]) -> "Text"
    };
styleConvert[s_String] :=
  Sequence @@ Flatten@List@Catch[
      Scan[
       If[StringEndsQ[s, #], Throw@#] &,
       {
        "Text",
        "Link"
        }
       ];
      KeyValueMap[
       If[StringEndsQ[s, #], Throw[#2]] &,
       Join[
        <|
         "Listing" -> "Text",
         "TableMod" :> {"Input", "DetailsGrid"}
         |>,
        AssociationThread[
         NestList[StringReplace["S" -> "Subs"], "Section", 5],
         NestList[StringReplace["S" -> "Subs"], "Subsection", 5]
         ]
        ]
       ];
      Replace[s, fallbackStyleConversions]
      ];
styleConvert[e___] := e
```

#### Data Cleaning

Some times the actual `BoxData` the built-in docs use is unnecessarily complicated. To make this simpler we'll sometimes want to post-process this like:

```
convertUsageData // Clear;

convertUsageData[TextData[l_List]] :=
  Replace[
   Join @@@ Partition[
     SplitBy[
      Flatten@
       Reap[
         Replace[l,
          {
           Cell[a_, "InlineFormula", o___] :>
            Sow@Cell[a, "Code", "UsageInput", o],
           e : Except[_Cell] :> Sow[e],
           _ -> Nothing
           },
          1
          ]
         ][[2]],
      Head[#] === Cell &
      ],
     2
     ],
   {
    {c_Cell, s___} :>
     ReplaceAll[
      {
       c, 
       Cell[TextData[{s}], "Text", "UsageText"]
       },
      {
       r_String :> StringDelete[r, "\[LineSeparator]" | "\n"],
       StyleBox[a_, style_String, b___] :>
        RuleCondition[StyleBox[a, styleConvert[style], b], True]
       }
      ]
    },
   1
   ];

cleanUpInterpBoxes[InterpretationBox[a_, b_]] :=
  a;
cleanUpInterpBoxes[
   InterpretationBox[GridBox[{{a_, ___}, ___}, ___], b_]] :=
  a;

cellDataConvert // Clear
cellDataConvert[Cell[data_, "Usage", o___]] :=
  Sequence @@ {
    Cell[
     CellGroupData[Flatten@{
        Cell["", "UsageSection"],
        convertUsageData[data],
        Cell["", "UsageSectionFooter"]
        }]
     ],
    Cell["Details", "Subsection"]
    };
cellDataConvert[Cell[data_, "ExampleDelimiter", o___]] :=

 cellDataConvert@Cell["", "GuideDelimiter"]
cellDataConvert[
   Cell[data_, _String?(StringEndsQ["Delimiter"]), o___]] :=

  Cell["", "PageBreak", 
   PageBreakWithin -> False,
   PageBreakBelow -> False, 
   PageBreakAbove -> False
   ];
cellDataConvert[Cell[data_, k : "DisplayMath", o___]] :=
 Cell[
  FirstCase[data, f_FormBox :> BoxData[f], data, Infinity], 
  styleConvert[k],
  o
  ]
cellDataConvert[
   Cell[data_, s_String?(StringStartsQ["Example"]), o___]] :=
  Cell[
   data /. i_InterpretationBox :> cleanUpInterpBoxes[i],
   styleConvert[s],
   o
   ];
cellDataConvert[Cell["XXXX", ___]] :=
  Nothing;
cellDataConvert[Cell[data_, style_, o___]] :=
  Cell[data /. {
     c_Cell :> cellDataConvert[c],
     StyleBox[a_, s_String, b___] :>
      RuleCondition[StyleBox[a, styleConvert[s], b], True]
     },
    styleConvert[style], 
   o
   ];
cellDataConvert~SetAttributes~Listable;
```

### Stitching it all together

I don't want to copy all of this code out here, since I don't think that'd be a good use of the space. Instead I'll just mention that all of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/SimpleDocs/blob/abcca9348dd63a5e73cfcadeaaff814be80e5712/Packages/Package/SimpleDocs.m#L3491).

We can use it through [SimpleDocs](https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/simpledocs.html) too if we want. Here's how you pull the data from a function page (the same works for guides and tutorials too):

```
SimpleDocs@"WorkbenchData"["~/Desktop/FindEcoEvoEq.nb"] // Keys

{"Metadata", "Preamble", "Body", "RelatedTutorials", \
"RelatedDemonstrations", "RelatedLinks", "RelatedFunctions", \
"RelatedGuides", "Examples"}
```

And here's how you then reconvert that into a notebook that SimpleDocs can process:

```
SimpleDocs@"FromWorkbench"[
   "~/Desktop/FindEcoEvoEq.nb",
   "Directory" -> "~/Desktop/EcoEvo"
   ];
"~/Desktop/EcoEvo/project/docs/content/ref/FindEcoEvoEq.nb" // 
  ExpandFileName // SystemOpen
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm just having time to give this a try.  When I run `SimpleDocs@"FromWorkbench"`, it seems to work but beeps.  `Why the Beep?...` says `The shared stylesheet "Wolfram/FunctionPageStyles.nb" could not be found. The default stylesheet will be used instead.`  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @ChrisK that's because I need to open the Workbench notebook to use some FE programming tricks on it and when I do so it complains about the stylesheet. I could add a little hack that forces it to open with the `Default` styles...

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I get the same beep & message with Workbench, so I think my problem isn't related to your package.